# PHP Regex to preg_replace hypen with underscore if word has colon at the end

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got a JSON response and I'm trying to replace only the hypen ( - ) with an underscore (_) for consistency in the PHP, using preg_replace.

Example;

```
[
  {
    "name": "Disable Comments",
    "slug": "disable-comments",
    "required": true,
    "force-activation": true,
    "force-deactivation": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Intuitive Custom Post Order",
    "slug": "intuitive-custom-post-order",
    "required": true,
    "force-activation": false,
    "force-deactivation": true
  }
]
```

I'm trying to target only the keys, so anything ending with a colon. I've tried so many variations but can't seem to get close.

Comment: Please post the code showing what you've tried; that will help you get better answers.

Comment: I would parse the JSON, then loop over the arrays and replace the keys, rather than try to do this directly to the JSON.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it on the decoded array rather than on the JSON itself.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($array as &$subarray) { // Use reference so we can modify the subarray in place
    foreach ($subarray as $key => $value) {
        $new_key = str_replace('-', '_', $key);
        if ($new_key != $key) {
            $subarray[$new_key] = $value;
            unset($subarray[$key]);
        }
    }
}

$json = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: The above works, but not if keys are nested deeper within the JSON object/array.  I know that's outside the scope of the original question, but just wanted to point it out should others find this thread and try use on a multidimensional array.

Comment: That's true. It would be relatively straightforward to put this into a function and make it recurse into sub-arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It is an inadvisable technique to make string manipulations on a json encoded string -- the risk of accidentally/silently mutating unintended targets is simply not worth microscopic performance gains (if there are any).

It is better / more reliable to parse and iterate the data then specifically target the keys for replacement.

A functional approach: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HcoHa))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function($subarray) {
            return array_combine(
                    str_replace('-', '_', array_keys($subarray)),
                    $subarray
                );
        },
        json_decode($json, true)
    )
);
```

Looping via language construct and modifying by reference: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bITE6))

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array as &$subarray) {
    $subarray = array_combine(
                    str_replace('-', '_', array_keys($subarray)),
                    $subarray
                );
}
var_export($array);
```

Generate new array without array_combine: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PiYBG))

```
foreach (json_decode($json, true) as $index =>$subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $key => $value) {
        $array[$index][str_replace('-', '_', $key)] = $value;
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

These techniques could be mixed-n-matched based on personal preference.  One developer may prefer functional techniques because they require fewer declared variables.  Other developers may seek the performance gains of using laguage constructs and a minimal number of function calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/\"([^\"]*)\":/", function($m){
   return str_replace("-", "_", $m[0]);
}, $jsonStr);
```

Comment: There is simply too much wrong with this post.  1. Don't hack at a json string; parse it and target what is desired 2. Your pattern is not guaranteed to target ONLY keys -- regex is nit key-aware. 3. There is no explanation with this code-only answer.